# Can webdriver verify multiple information on a webpage dynamically?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium webdriver java, I have been trying to verify that each product listed on this page: https://www.gumtree.com/cars/london carries complete product details like year, engine size etc. I tried returning the page source with code:`

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

but the output is too verbose. One way I am looking to achieve this is to perhaps assert or `getText` of each product info for every listed product on the page but this will cause problems as the page gets updated. Is there a clever and dynamic way to achieve the task at hand?

Comment: In order to verify something is correct, you have to have something to compare it against. So, it depends on what you are trying to verify. If you are trying to verify that the year, mileage, engine type, engine size is all there... there are ways to do this. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to verify that each product has complete product details - year, fuel type etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the products listed on that page do not update unless the browser is refreshed, so there should be no issue with following through on your idea of running assertions on each product's content.

You can store a list of all the currently listed results and iterate through them:

```
@Test
    public void checkProductFields() throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = getDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.gumtree.com/cars/london");

        List<WebElement> productList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@data-q='featuredresults' or @data-q='naturalresults']/li/article"));

        for (WebElement product : productList) {
            String year = product.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@itemprop='releaseDate']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
            String mileage = product.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@itemprop='vehicleMileage']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
            String fuelType = product.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@itemprop='vehicleFuelType']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
            String engineSize = product.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@itemprop='vehicleEngineSize']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

            //Assertions...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will try this, thanks. When you say //Assertions..., I am assuming I have to continue with running assertions on each product's content. Right? Will I be able to download or print all the product details to console, this way?

Comment: Correct. You should assert that, for each particular product, you get values back, as well as run separate assertions for each type (e.g. year is non-negative, 4 digit, not in the future, etc..). You can use `System.out.println()` to verify for yourself that you are retrieving the correct strings before proceeding.

Comment: I am find this useful. Thanks. I am trying the same approach you specified above on a similar webpage: https://www.auto1.com/en/our-cars but I am unable to generate the xpath for the string, to use in the for loop, like the previous site and this is because both pages have a different layout for the product details. I will be glad if you can help with this

Comment: For the second site, you need to use something like `//li[@class='car-item']`. This will locate all `li` tags with attribute `class="car-item"`. I suggest reading a tutorial on xpath selectors such as [link](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XPath_tutorial_-_basics). Also, if my original answer has satisfied your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.